# Using present continuous for tendencies

Tags: present-tense, continuous-aspect

Can one use present continuous to describe tendencies, such as:

> Oh this word? It's not being actively used these days anymore.

This sounds good to me, but I can't find a grammar rule to support this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Will people understand that? Yes, but people would generally say or write:

> Oh, this word? It's not used anymore.

In your sentence, the adverb "actively" is extraneous. Is there a way for a word to be inactively used? No, there isn't. Also, "anymore" already expresses what "these days" expresses, which makes "these days" redundant.

Comment: +1 I agree for the sentence in question, but the present continuous is still used quite regularly in regards to tendency.  For example,  "Nobody is playing that game anymore."